# Understanding the method javax.persistence.EntityManager.refresh(Object entity)

Tags: java, entitymanager, hibernate-entitymanager, jpa

Can anyone please help me understand the implementation and application of the method javax.persistence.EntityManager.refresh(Object entity)

I was going through the documentation for the method: 
void javax.persistence.EntityManager.refresh(Object entity)

The url for details about the method is :
https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#refresh-java.lang.Object

The description for the method says:

"Refresh the state of the instance from the database, overwriting changes made to the entity, if any."

So, "refreshing the state of instance from the database" implies that the next read on the same entity/instance should give the result of most recent updates. I am not able to interpret the next part of the description which says: "overwriting changes made to the entity, if any."

Thank you!

Comment: `entity.setFoo("bar"); em.refresh(entity);` will overwrite the change you made by calling `setFoo("bar")`.

Comment: What if I commit the transaction after `entity.setFoo("bar")`

Comment: The method will do what its documentation says: it will refresh the state from the database. Since the database contains "bar", the entity will contain "bar".